# Javascript replace plus sign with space (but not %20)

Tags: javascript, riot-games-api

I am trying to use the League of Legends API and request data on a certain user. I use the line

```
    var user = getUrlVars()["username"].replace("+", " ");
```

to store the username. However, when I do the XMLHttpRequest with that username, it'll put %20 instead of a space.

```
y.open("GET", "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+user, false);
```

Edit: When I run this code with a user that has no space in their name it works, however when they have a space in their name it says the user is undefined.

For example, if I was looking for the user "the man", it would do a get at

```
https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/the%20man
```

But the correct request URL is

```
https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/the man
```

Comment: %20 is a space and is the correct way to encode it.

Comment: I should work with %20. Space in your case bade pattern. Your binder should work with %20 and convert to correct value.

Comment: I guess I should've said this but I get an error when I run it with the %20 URL.

Comment: The webserver is supposed to translate the `%` codes back to the native character. URLs aren't allowed to contain spaces, they have to be encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're creating a URL, you should use `encodeURIComponent` to encode all the special characters properly:

```
y.open("GET", "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+encodeURIComponent(user), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is correct behaviour and is called URL encoding. HTTP requests have to conform to certain standards. The first line is always made up of three parts delimited by a space:

1. Method (GET, POST, etc.)
2. Path (i.e. /api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/the%20man)
3. HTTP version (HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0, etc.)

This is usually followed by HTTP headers which I'll leave out for the time being since it is beyond the scope of your question (if interested, read this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). So a normal request looks like this:

```
GET /api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/the%20man HTTP/1.1
Host: na.api.pvp.net
User-Agent: Mozilla
...
```

With regards to your original question, the reason the library is URL encoding the space to `%20` is because you cannot have a space character in the request line. Otherwise, you would throw off most HTTP message parsers because the `man` would replace the HTTP version line like so:

```
GET /api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/the man HTTP/1.1
Host: na.api.pvp.net
User-Agent: Mozilla
...
```

In most cases, servers will return a 400 bad request response because they wouldn't understand what HTTP version `man` refers to. However, nothing to fear hear, most server-side applications/frameworks automatically decode the `%20` or `+` to space prior to processing the data in the HTTP request. So even though your URL looks unusual, the server side will process it as `the man`.

Finally, one last thing to note. You shouldn't be using the `String.replace()` to URL decode your messages. Instead, you should be using decodeURI() and encodeURI() for decoding and encoding strings, respectively. For example:

```
var user = getUrlVars()["username"].replace("+", " ");
```

becomes

```
var user = decodeURI(getUrlVars()["username"]);
```

This ensures that usernames containing special characters (like `/` which would be URL encoded as `%2f`) are also probably decoded. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are no "spaces" in the summoner names on Riot's side.  So:

```
https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/the man
```

Becomes:

```
https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/theman
```

Have a look at this: https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/community-discussion/show/jomoRum7

I am unsure how + are handled (in fact I don't think you're able to have a + in your name). All you have to do is remove the spaces.

For "funny" characters, just request them with the funny character in them, and Riot returned it fine.

```
https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Trøyer?api_key=<insert your own>
```

will auto correct to

```
https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Tr%C3%B8yer?api_key=<insert your own>
```

and you generally don't even have to decode it.  (I used JS as my language to fetch it, if you use something else your results may require the decoded value)